# NSView .transform equivalent?

Tags: swift, macos, uiimageview, storyboard, nsimageview

Sorry if I've missed something really obvious here but I'm still quite new to programming :)

So I'm trying to rotate an image view for a mac application, and I found out that in IOS for a UIImageView you can use this code:

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
```

However, for OSX NSImageView doesn't seem to have .transform available.

Is there any alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late, but here you go:

```
myImageView.wantsLayer = true
myImageView.layer?.transform = // Your transformation right here
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely late but hope it helps someone

Swift 5:

`let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 1.0) myImageView.wantsLayer = true myImageView.layer?.setAffineTransform(transform)`